# Scaffold-DbContext Instance failure - create models from existing database (project with Individual Identity)

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I created a database with few tables like user, userRole, role and I created project in .net Core with EFCore5 with Individual Identity. I tried to run

> > Scaffold-DbContext 'Server=**\**;database=___;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

to generate models but I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Instance failure.
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
> Instance failure.

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using localhost? Are you using SQLServer Express or the full version?

Comment: Check your connection string by manually connecting to it using same server and credentials

Comment: @Andre.Santarosa  SQLServer Express

Comment: @DarshaniJayasekara manually it works

Comment: Try that: `Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS ;database=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true`

Comment: you can always use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools make it very for scaffolding database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Services -> SQL Server Browser - turn on
2. Windows Firefall -> Inbound Rule -> New Rule - Port, TCP, All local ports, Allow the connection -> Add
3. In this role propperties -> protocols and ports -> Protocol Type - All
4. Sql server 20** Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> TCP/IP -> IP Adsress -> Enabled - yes | TCP dynamic posts - empty | TCP Port - 1433
5. Services - restart Sql server

Also thanks for advice to use EF Core Power Tools.